# how to change response format from fast_jsonapi format to AMS gem response format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers, fastjsonapi

I want to change The response format of fast_jsonapi gem from:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "8",
        "type": "directory",
        "attributes": {
            "firstname": "Naoufal",
            "lastname": "Huster",
        }
    }
}
```

To this:

```
{
  "id": "8",
  "firstname": "Naoufal",
  "lastname": "Huster",
}
```

I'm migrating from using AMS gem to using fast_jsonapi, I want to use fast_jsonapi but keep the same response json format of AMS when rendering data.

Ruby 2.5.0
Rails 5.2.1
fast_jsonapi gem

Comment: The fastjson api format is fixed and cannot be modified.

Comment: [fast_jsonapi](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi) use [JSON:API](http://jsonapi.org/) (read the first line of [REAME.md](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi/blob/master/README.md) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not possible. `fastjson_api` gem follows the [json api](http://jsonapi.org/) standard.

Also, a similar question was asked in the repo: [source](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi/issues/204)

Comment: Is there a way to do the conversion from json_api standard to the other format in a model or something?

Comment: I would suggest you using another gem (like AMS).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sparse fieldsets](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi#sparse-fieldsets) to selectively choose which fields you want.

```
class MovieSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer

  attributes :name, :year
end

serializer = MovieSerializer.new(movie, { fields: { movie: [:name] } })
serializer.serializable_hash
```

If you need the data flattened even further, you can create a helper method to manually flatten out the JSON or you can try to flatten it using the standard `.flatten` function on an array or hash depending on your data format. You cannot perform flatten if you've already stringified it into JSON.